# Reveal div only when user is scrolled all the way up

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, slidetoggle

I've been fiddling with slideToggle and have created an info box on the left side of my webpage that is revealed when the user activates the "Click Here to Toggle!" href.

I want the "Click Here to Toggle!" link (which is contained within its own div) to only be visible when the user is scrolled all the way up to the top of the page

I apologize for any noobiness, I am slowly teaching myself web design for fun :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can log the scroll position of the viewport using the `scrollTop()` property of the window object, and then use a logical statement to decide when to display the link depending on the `scrollTop()` value.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $("#target").hide();
        } else {
            $("#target").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/sBNEJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could do something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($('html').offset().top == 0){
     $('#yourdiv').show();
  }else{
      $('#yourdiv').hide();
  }
});
```

That will display a div when you scroll and your position is at the top. If you scroll and your new position is not at the top it will hide the div.